# How do I get dog poo from the yard to the toilet?

Tags: dogs, defecation

Our medium-sized (45 lbs?) pit bull dog mostly poops in our grassy back yard, and currently we scoop all that poop into a bag and trash it. The poops are usually firm. But bagging & trashing doesn't seem like the sustainable choice!

Instead, the metro area where I live [recommends flushing dog poop](http://www.metrovancouver.org/services/solid-waste/detached-homes/reduce-garbage-home/dog-poo/Pages/default.aspx) in the toilet. That seems like it could be a good idea, but I'm stuck thinking about the best way to get dog poop from outside on the grass to inside in the toilet without stinking up the house. It's important that only the poop is flushed, which means doggy bags (compostable or otherwise) aren't allowed. And the scooper tool is open on top, so if I used that to carry the dog poo inside the smell would just waft everywhere.

For people who have experience flushing dog poo, how do you move it from the yard into the toilet without making the house smell bad?

---

*PS. I still plan to use doggy bags for picking up poop during our trips to the park.*

Comment: What size dog do you have (which will affect the amount of poop to be moved each time), and does your dog generally have firmer or softer stools (which will affect how easy it is to move)?

Comment: Medium sized female pit bull, generally firm poops.

Comment: I found a garden hose with nozzle will wash it away easily.

Comment: My parents in law have a compost (black barrel shaped plastic box with cover) for the poo of their dog in a silent corner of their yard. It does not smell or disturb in other kinds.

Comment: You might want to consider a [Doggie Dooley](https://doggiedooley.com) and put it at the edge of your lawn.